# Dismissed jobs in "Looking for a job" still show up in search results

Tags: bug, stack-overflow-jobs, advertising

When I dismiss a job in the looking for a job advertisement why does it still show up in job search?

[image]

It seems as though the two functions are not equal and are separate in terms of how this all works. I would think they would be one and the same.  For instance, in the above screenshot if I dismiss the first item and then go to SO Jobs this item appears right away.

Comment: Stop fighting it and accept your destiny as a .NET Application Architect at United Shore in Troy, MI.

Comment: I removed the [status-review] tag from this post because the Jobs product no longer exists.

Answer (score 13):

There are at least two problems here to fix.

One issue is that there is currently no way in job search itself to dismiss a job.  We're reviewing that issue -- we have designs and just have a little more work to do on requirements before scheduling build of that feature.  As with basically every feature that isn't being developed *right now,* I can't tell you exactly when we'll get to it, but it's on our radar near-term.

The other issue is that job ads and job search are nowhere near as integrated as we would like.  For example, job ads don't currently use *all* of your job preferences (though I'm told that's changing soon).  Another example is the one you raise; once we have a way to dismiss jobs in job search, it will make sense to allow dismissal in job search to dismiss the same job in ads and vice versa.

So, I'm marking this one [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) for now.  We have some planning work to do before we get this implemented.

Comment: So likely in 6-8 weeks.