# Dismiss Company Ad - Block Company Entirely

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs, advertising

I know we can easily dismiss job ads as laid out here: [Allow users to hide individual job listings](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312509/allow-users-to-hide-individual-job-listings/331771#331771)

[And I know there is currently a bug such that when you dismiss the job ad it doesn't get dismissed from your job searches.  But I am told this is status review.  I am fine with that.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358305/dismissed-jobs-in-looking-for-a-job-still-show-up-in-search-results)

I recently interviewed at a company I found here on SO Jobs. Ultimately they offered me a position and I declined.  However, this company ad is littered all over Stack Overflow when I log in, as they are very local to me.

I'd like to not see this company advertised for me anymore as I don't want anything to do with them.  However, you cannot dismiss company ads.

### Feature Request

Can we please add the ability to dismiss company ads and store this information such that I don't see it again.  I'd also like to block certain companies.

Comment: Related - [Is there a way to block an employer request after the fact?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/313016/1079354)

Comment: Would be awesome. I really don't like to see company adds, that require me to be a US citizen and have security clearance. I will never qualify for those jobs. I'd prefer to see some Jobs that *could* be interesting to me.

Comment: related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345399/jobs-how-to-block-an-employer-before-any-contact?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: I wonder if the question asker should ping stackoverflow via email privately. It may not necessarily get the company's ads removed, but knowing the actual details could be useful in prioritizing this and adding to the rationale of such a feature. I want to point out that the question as presented here is certainly not lacking detail - the unambiguified abstraction/normalization is "textbook stackoverflow" - but that may mean it'll just get lost in the sea of other reports. (OT: this will be the 14th thing in Google's entire index to use the word "unambiguified".)

Answer (score 13):

We've shipped this today!

You can now dismiss jobs and companies altogether. We're syncing this information with the ads system, so that you won't see jobs you dismiss on /jobs on ads (and the other way around).

Dismissed jobs also won't make it into jobs emails or appear as results on any searches.

Comment: Does this apply to companies that have advertised at any point in time with the system (just in case they pop back up)?

Comment: @Makoto I'm not sure I understand the question... but you can dismiss any company [on our company index](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/companies) even if they don't have jobs right now. If they created jobs in the future, you wouldn't see those jobs (except in ads, where we have a cache that may need up to 24 hours to be cleared)

Comment: I was more referring to jobs that have since been removed from the company index.  I'm willing to bet that at one point, the company I wanted to filter had since stopped advertising on Stack Overflow, but it'd be useful to be able to block them (as far as I'm concerned, anyway) should they ever attempt to make a comeback.

Comment: @Makoto send me the company name via email and I’ll check what’s the status of that company (if they still have the company page, even if disabled, I can dismiss it for you)

Comment: Looks like I managed to track them down.  Thanks for looking out.  I'll also consider my [prior question on this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/313016/1079354) a dupe to this one.